# Font for hats differs in web and in the iOS app

Tags: bug, ios-app

Font used in hats differs in web and in the iOS app.

- web:

> [image: web]

- iOS app:

> [image: ios]

- App Version: 1.6.2.5
- Device: iPad Air 2 (Wi-Fi)
- OS Version: Version 10.2 (Build 14C92)